# Can't install purr R package

Tags: software-installation, r

I am trying to install the purr package on R but it seems something is not working properly. I am using an Ubuntu Xenial (16.04) and R 3.4.2. The error message I receive is:

```
> install.packages("purrr")
Installing package into '/home/rus/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/purrr_0.2.3.tar.gz'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/purrr_0.2.3.tar.gz'
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: It looks like the version of `purrr` at cran.rstudio.com has recently been bumped to 0.2.4. I don't know how `install.packages()` tracks what version to pull - maybe you need to update other packages?

Comment: Hi, how can I know which package should be updated. I realize that R in Windows looks for the 0.2.4 version but in Ubuntu checks for 0.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 16.04 LTS. I have added [R-Cran repository](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) and I'm able to install `purrr` package (0.2.4 was installed).

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when package versions get bumped on CRAN and you happen to ping the server during the transition (because the PACKAGES index file on the server wasn't yet updated following the archival of the old version and the upload of the new version). The problem usually resolves itself within an hour or so, but you can still install the updated package version directly:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/purrr_0.2.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL)
```